# Postmapping not getting called when api called from angular to spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I have a service class `book.service.ts` as:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Book } from '../common/book';
import { BookCategory } from '../common/book-category';
import { Finalcart } from '../common/finalcart';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {

  private finalCart="http://localhost:8080/api/test/";

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  addFinalCart(finalCart:Finalcart){

  return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}`+'finalCart',finalCart, httpOptions);   
}
```

The service method
`addFinalCart(finalCart:Finalcart)` is getting called from component.ts file :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout',
  templateUrl: './checkout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkout.component.css']
})
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {

  cartItems: CartItem[] = [];
  totalPrice: number = 0;
  totalQuantity: number = 0;
  checkoutFormGroup: FormGroup;
   finalCart:Finalcart;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private _cartService: CartService,
    private _bookService:BookService) { }

 
  ngOnInit() {
//I have not included all codes,only the required ones.
   }
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.checkoutFormGroup.invalid) {
      return;
  }
  console.log(this.cartItems);
  console.log('Purchase the books');
      let finalCart=new Finalcart(this.checkoutFormGroup.value.billingAddress,
    this.checkoutFormGroup.value.shippingAddress, this.checkoutFormGroup.value.creditCard, this.cartItems);
    
    console.log('finalcart is',finalCart);
    this._bookService.addFinalCart(this.finalCart);
  }
}
```

So,I have the JWT authentication and I have been already logged in successfully and while calling api :

```
http://localhost:8080/api/test/finalCart
```

The api that I am exposing in spring boot is not called.However,when I called the api from postman then,the api is being called successfully in spring boot,but from postman I have passed the token information also,but while from service class of angular I haven't send the user information.

```
package in.ashwin.onlinebookstore.controller;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userdetailService;
    
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRep;
    
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookrepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private CartItemRepository cartItemRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    private OrderDetailsRepository orderDetailRepostiory;
    

    
    @Autowired
    private BillingaddressRepository billAddressRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    private ShippingaddressRepository shippingAddressRepo;
    
    @PostMapping("/finalCart")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String finalCart(@RequestBody Finalcart finalCart,HttpServletRequest request) {
        String user=request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
       System.out.println(user);
       
       System.out.println(finalCart);
    
       UserDetailsImpl userDetails=(UserDetailsImpl)userdetailService.loadUserByUsername(user);
        User u=new User(userDetails.getId(),userDetails.getUsername(),userDetails.getPassword(),userDetails.getEmail());
     Order ord= orderRep.save(new Order(u,new Date()));
     System.out.println(ord);
     
     
     
    Billingaddress ba= billAddressRepo.save(new Billingaddress(finalCart.getBillingAddress(),ord));
    System.out.println(ba);
     
     Shippingaddress sa=shippingAddressRepo.save(new Shippingaddress(finalCart.getShippingAddress(),ord));
     System.out.println(sa);
     
     finalCart.getCartItem().forEach(s->{
         Optional<Book> b=bookrepository.findById(Long.valueOf(s.getBookId()).longValue());
        CartItem c=cartItemRepo.save(new CartItem(s.getName(),s.getImageUrl(),s.getUnitPrice(),s.getQuantity(), b.get()));
        orderDetailRepostiory.save(new OrderDetails(c,ord));    
     });
     
     
       System.out.println(userDetails.getUsername()+userDetails.getPassword());
        System.out.println("entered here");
        System.out.println(finalCart);
        System.out.println(finalCart.getBillingAddress());
        System.out.println(finalCart.getShippingAddress());
        System.out.println(finalCart.getCreditCard());
        return "null";
    }
}
```

I see there is nothing printed in my console in eclipse.I think I made mistake while sending information from angular service class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `addFinaCart` inorder for API call to work

```
this._bookService.addFinalCart(this.finalCart).subscribe(
        (response) => {
        console.log(response.body);
        },
       (err)=>{
       console.log("Error",err); //======> In case of failure
       }
)
```

Comment: Since I have two parameter in spring boot finalCart(@RequestBody Finalcart finalCart,HttpServletRequest request)  , I got error since there is HttpServletRequest. How can I set it as required false from angular service method?

Comment: my api is being called when I put the subscribe methos